# How can I replace a substring in a Python pathlib.Path?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pathlib

Is there an easy way to replace a substring within a `pathlib.Path` object in Python? The [pathlib module is nicer in many ways](https://realpython.com/python-pathlib/) than storing a path as a `str` and using `os.path`, `glob.glob` etc, which are built in to `pathlib`. But I often use files that follow a pattern, and often replace substrings in a path to access other files:

```
data/demo_img.png
data/demo_img_processed.png
data/demo_spreadsheet.csv
```

Previously I could do:

```
img_file_path = "data/demo_img.png"
proc_img_file_path = img_file_path.replace("_img.png", "_img_proc.png")
data_file_path = img_file_path.replace("_img.png", "_spreadsheet.csv")
```

`pathlib` can replace the file extension with the `with_suffix()` method, but only accepts extensions as valid suffixes. The workarounds are:

```
import pathlib
import os


img_file_path = pathlib.Path("data/demo_img.png")
proc_img_file_path = pathlib.Path(str(img_file_path).replace("_img.png", "_img_proc.png"))
# os.fspath() is available in Python 3.6+ and is apparently safer than str()
data_file_path = pathlib.Path(os.fspath(img_file_path).replace("_img.png", "_img_proc.png"))
```

Converting to a string to do the replacement and reconverting to a `Path` object seems laborious. Assume that I never have a copy of the string form of `img_file_path`, and have to convert the type as needed.

Comment: Whatever you do, beware of using `Path.replace` as as attempted substitute - not the same thing, and **can clobber existing data on filesystem**!

Comment: That's right. I luckily read the documentation before trying. `replace()`  will rename the current file to the target, and replace it if the file already exists.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You are correct. To replace old with new in Path p, you need:

```
p = Path(str(p).replace(old, new))
```

---

EDIT

We turn Path p into str so we get this str method:

> Help on method_descriptor:
>
> replace(self, old, new, count=-1, /)
>
> Return a copy with all occurrences of substring old replaced by new.

Otherwise we'd get this Path method:

> Help on function replace in module pathlib:
>
> replace(self, target)
>
> Rename this path to the given path, clobbering the existing destination if it exists, and return a new Path instance pointing to the given path.

Comment: Nice answer.  Although I don't think you need to cast to a `str`, so that may be unnecessary.

Comment: Yes, it is necessary to cast to `str`.  Otherwise it will call `pathlib.Path`'s `replace` method which does not do the same thing.

Comment: Just a small complementation: Alternatively to `str(p)`, pathlib’s [`p.as_posix()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.as_posix) can also be used.

Answer (score 3):

use PurePath.with_name() or PurePath.with_stem()

Answer (score 2):

I have recently faced a similar problem and found this thread when searching for a solution. In contrast to the accepted answer I did not convert the `pathlib.Path` object into a string. Instead, I used its [`parent`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.parent) and [`name`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.name) attributes (`name` is a string itself), along with the [`joinpath()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.joinpath) method. Here is the code:

```py
In [2]: from pathlib import Path

In [3]: img_file_path = Path('data/demo_img.png')

In [4]: parent, name = img_file_path.parent, img_file_path.name

In [5]: proc_fn = name.replace('_img.png', '_img_proc.png')
   ...: data_fn = name.replace('_img.png', '_spreadsheet.csv')

In [6]: proc_img_file_path = Path(parent).joinpath(proc_fn)
   ...: data_img_file_path = Path(parent).joinpath(data_fn)

In [7]: proc_img_file_path
Out[7]: WindowsPath('data/demo_img_proc.png')

In [8]: data_img_file_path
Out[8]: WindowsPath('data/demo_spreadsheet.csv')
```

An advantage of this approach is that it avoids the risk of making unwanted replacements in the parent bit.

Comment: True. It's often enough I will favor `re.sub(r'\.png$', '.csv', fname)` over .replace(), for safety's sake. On this question I stuck with OP's use of .replace().

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on [ibykovsky's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70322687/353062), the `.with_name()` and `.with_stem()` methods are a clean way of solving this in 3.9+.  In common with [Tonechas' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68855243/353062), this avoids any risk of inadvertently changing the parent part.

For the example in the question, we can write:

```py
import pathlib

p = pathlib.Path("data/demo_img.png")
# Simple case of appending extra text to the Path.stem does not need to use str.replace()
p_proc = p.with_stem(p.stem + "_proc")
# More complex case uses str.replace() on the Path.name
p_data = p.with_name(p.name.replace("_img.png", "_spreadsheet.csv"))
```

The first substitution is simply appending a string to the stem, so does not need to use `str.replace()`. Note, however that doing it via the stem means that the substitution will be made whatever the suffix (e.g., for `.jpg` as well as `.png`), which is different from the OP. This may or may not be what you want.

Swapping the suffix can be done with `.with_suffix()` but if substitutions are required in the parent parts, then this approach would become more unwieldy. There is no `.with_parent()` method, although `.with_segments()` is introduced in 3.12